# How to check if values are greater than 7 by only using bitwise operators in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, twos-complement

For this question, it asks to return 1 if the argument is greater than 7, and 0 otherwise.

For example, if x is 8, the function will return 1. If x is 7, the function will return 0.

The only legal operators allowed are  (! ~ & ^ | + << >>), which forbids the use of anything else such as -, for loops, while loops, if statements, etc.

We can assume the system uses 2's complement and a 32 bit representation of integers, performs right shifts arithmetically, and has unpredictable behavior when shifting an integer by more than the word size.

I know that subtracting without using the - operation can be done with ~, but I don't know how to think of this one logically to be honest.

Comment: Hint: which bits are set in a number larger than 7?

Comment: @dbush The answer depends a good deal on whether the negative numbers are allowed or not :-)

Comment: "[U]ses 2's complement" is a statement about how the machine represents negative integers.  Are we to conclude that this is in fact a concern?  That is, what is the data type of the value to be tested?  `int`? `int32_t`?  `unsigned int`? `uint32_t`? Something else?

Comment: @JohnBollinger It seems like the given conditions are describing how bitwise operators work on signed numbers, since the C spec leaves that implementation-dependent.

Comment: @Barmar, except inasmuch as bitwise operations can, in principle, yield trap representations, among the bitwise operators it is only the shifts that have any implementation-defined behavior.  But that is tangential to the question I posed: what is the data type of the input?

Comment: I downvoted because these "How can I do task A *without* using obvious language features X, Y, or Z?" questions are silly puzzles which have no place in serious programming, and essentially no value for future readers.

Answer (score 6):

In binary, the decimal number `7` is `111`. Hence, a number which is greater than seven will always have a more significant bit set than the most significant bit in the binary representation of 7 (i.e. bit 3 when numbering from 0) set. So, if you are dealing only with *unsigned numbers* then this test is sufficient:

```
int bitwise_is_n_gt_7 (unsigned int value)
{
    return value & 0xFFFFFFF8; // assuming size 32-bits adjust as  necessary
}
```

If you are dealing with signed numbers you have to also deal with the possibility that a number is negative, so you then test for:

```
int bitwise_is_n_gt_7 (int value)
{
    return (!!(value & 0x7FFFFFF8) & !(value & 0x80000000));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

>7 is the same as ≥8.

You can check if a positive number is ≥ another positive number using integer division. It's larger if the result is non-zero.

Division isn't a "bit operation", but eight is a power of two, and there's a "bit operation" that's defined as a division by a power of 2: `>>`

So we could use:

```c
n >> 3
```

Right-shifting a positive integer by three removes the three least-significant bits while moving the others. But we don't care if the others are moved or not.

So we could also use:

```c
n & ~7
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for negative numbers (as stated in the answer).

Comment: @Fe2O3 ack! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If an unsigned number is `7` or less, then the only bits that will be set will be bits that represent `4` or `2` or `1`.
The next higher bit represents `8`, which is greater than 7.

So, if you "turn off" the lowest 3 bits (which represent `4`, `2`, and `1`), with masking, and check if any bits still remain on, then the original number was 8 or greater.

```
if (number & ~0b0111) // Turn OFF the lowest 3 bits, keep all the others.
{
    printf("Number is 8 or Greater\n");
}
else 
{
    printf("Number is 7 or less\n");
}
```

Using the `0b` prefix is non-standard (but very common in many compilers), so you might choose to replace `0b0111` with `0x07`, or just plain-old `7` instead:

```
if (number & ~7)  { /* number is greater than 7 */ }
```

## Example Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    for(int i=0; i<30; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d is %s 7\n", i, i&~7? "greater than" :"less than (or equal to)");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
0 is less than (or equal to) 7
1 is less than (or equal to) 7
2 is less than (or equal to) 7
3 is less than (or equal to) 7
4 is less than (or equal to) 7
5 is less than (or equal to) 7
6 is less than (or equal to) 7
7 is less than (or equal to) 7
8 is greater than 7
9 is greater than 7
10 is greater than 7
```

---

Starting with this basic concept, and to handle negative numbers, you need to check if the "sign-bit" is set.  If it is set, the number is automatically negative, and automatically less than 7.

Breaking it all down:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {
    for(int i=-10; i<+10; ++i)
    {
        bool is_negative_bit_off = !(i>>31);
        bool is_bit_8_or_higher_set = !!(i&~7);

        if (is_negative_bit_off && is_bit_8_or_higher_set)
        {
            printf("%d is greater than 7\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And then simplifying it:

```
int main(void) {
    for(int i=-10; i<+10; ++i)
    {
        bool num_greater_than_7 = !(i>>31) & !!(i&~7);

        if (num_greater_than_7)
        {
            printf("%d is greater than 7\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So the final expression / answer to your question is:

```
bool num_greater_than_7 = !(i>>31) & !!(i&~7);
```

*(read as, "Is the Number Positive? And is the Number greater than 7?")*

Operators used are `!`, `>>`, `&` `~`.